# jobs command result is empty when process is run through script

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, jobs

I need to run rsync in background through shell script but once it has started, I need to monitor the status of that jobs through shell.

`jobs` command return empty when its run in shell after the script exits. `ps -ef | grep rsync` shows that the rsync is still running.

I can check the status through script but I need to run the script multiple times so it uses a different `ip.txt` file to push. So I can't have the script running to check `jobs` status.

Here is the script:

```
for i in `cat $ip.txt`; do
     rsync -avzh $directory/ user@"$i":/cygdrive/c/test/$directory 2>&1 > /dev/null &
done
jobs; #shows the jobs status while in the shell script.
exit 1
```

Output of `jobs` command is empty after the shell script exits:

```
root@host001:~# jobs
root@host001:~#
```

What could be the reason and how could I get the status of `jobs` while the `rsync` is running in background? I can't find an article online related to this.

Answer (score 1):

Since your shell (the one from which you execute `jobs`) did not start `rsync`, it doesn't know anything about it. There are different approaches to fixing that, but it boils down to starting the background process from your shell. For example, you can start the script you have using the `source` BASH command instead of executing it in a separate process. Of course, you'd have to remove the `exit 1` at the end, because that exits your shell otherwise.

Comment: Can you give me an example of source command? 
I tried `source rsync -avzh abcd user@host001:/cygwin/c/abcd` but it throws the following error `source: /usr/bin/rsync: cannot execute binary file`.

Comment: is it like `source ./script.sh`? Can't it be used scirpt like `source rsync -avzh ...`?

Comment: Remove `exit 1` from your script, then run it by doing `source myscript` or, even shorter `. myscript` (that's a dot there).

Comment: Type `help source` in your shell.